# hypergeometric distribution for $m$ colors

Tags: probability

Suppose we have an urn that contains balls of $m$ colors. Say $N_i$ is the number of balls of color $i$ where $i=1,...,m$. Let $N = N_1 + ... + N_m$. Suppose we draw $n$ balls without replacement. Let $X_i $ be the number of balls of color $i$ draw among $n$ balls. How Can I find an expresion for $P(X_1 = x_1,...,X_m = x_m) $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have already read the wikipedia page for the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) and want a derivation of its pmf.

How many ways are there to draw $x:= x_1+\cdots+x_m$ balls? Easy, $\binom{N}{x}$. How many of those ways have $X_i=x_i$ for each $i$? For each $i$ choose $x_i$ of the $N_i$ possibilities to get $\binom{N_i}{x_i}$ for each $i$, then put the results together for a grand total of $\prod_{i=1}^m \binom{N_i}{x_i}$.

Thus 
$$
P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_m=x_m) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^m \binom{N_i}{x_i}}{\binom{N}{x}}.
$$